# ImageButton with shape in android

Tags: android, shapes, android-imagebutton

I have a ImageButton and I used a shape to transform it in a circle. But when I try to change the color of the ImageButton the shape doesn't work, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: please share your work , so people can help you

Answer (score 1):

My code is here:

***Shape:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/material_grey_50" />
            <stroke android:color="@color/material_grey_500"
                android:width="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

***GridView Item:***

```
<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/buttonRemove"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="43dp"
   android:layout_weight="5"
   android:background="@color/material_cyan_300"
   android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_remove"/>
```

Comment: Whats the point of the selector instead of shape drawable? How are you even using/referencing it here?

Answer (score 0):

You can to use library: [CustomShapeImageView](https://github.com/MostafaGazar/CustomShapeImageView)

for example:

```
  <com.meg7.widget.CustomShapeImageView
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sample"
        app:shape="circle"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```